# Get first KeyValuePair in a dictionary that has a specific value

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, iteration, key-value

I'm writing an app in C#/.NET 4.5 and I have a dictionary defined like this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> d = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

My integer keys are sequential and unique and, except for empty strings, my values will be unique as well.  For example:

```
Key     Value
  0     AAAAAAAAAA
  1     BBBBBB
  2     (empty string)
  3     CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
  4     DDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
  5     EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
  6     (empty string)
```

When I have a new string to add to the dictionary, I need to assign it to one of the keys which has a value of (empty string).  Ideally, I'd like to do this at the first instance of such a key.  I'm currently looping through my dictionary like this:

```
int keyNumber;

foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in d)
{
    if (pair.Value == string.Empty)
    {
        keyNumber = pair.Key;
        break;
    }
}

d[keyNumber] = "new string goes here!";
```

This works but is there a better (or faster) way to accomplish the same thing?  If this actually is the best approach, is it possible to shorten it into a LINQ expression?

EDIT -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

I left out what was probably something important to explain.  The values that get loaded into my dictionary are actually loaded from a binary file comprised of fixed-length byte arrays which hold ASCII strings.  The file will always consist of 5000000 bytes or 100000 total strings @ 50 bytes each.  The file structure was determined by some hardware limitations on the device that will consume the file.  So the key for each KeyValuePair in my dictionary is actually used to determine the offset into the file where I need to write any changes when the user is finished making them.  For example, using a a key of 4, I then multiply by 50 to a starting offset of 200 bytes.  Then I write the modified string back at that location.  Sorry for omitting that in my original post.

Comment: It sounds like your keys have no relation to your values, and order doesn't matter... Why are you using a `Dictionary` then? Why not just use a `List`, and the index can be your `Key`?

Comment: Actually, my keys and values do need to have a relation.  I left out some detail but the data that gets loaded into the dictionary comes from a binary file comprised of fixed-length byte arrays that hold my ASCII strings (100000 total strings @ 50 bytes each).  The key in my dictionary is used by determine where in the binary file changes should be written (e.g., offset of 4 * 50 = 200 and then I read 50 bytes and decode the string "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDD").  Does that make sense?

Comment: I seriously doubt LINQ will be faster.  It has to enumerate and compare also.  So you are sure you will not run out of string.Empty?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to run out of string.Empty.  The file size is fixed and can only hold 100,000 ASCII-encoded strings @ 50 bytes each.  If there are no string.Empty values, then the user has to make room for more data by deleting some existing data.  Crazy as it may sound, it's a requirement.

Comment: If the keys are integer sequential, unique, and start with 0 why not just use string[100000] and let the ordinal position be the key.  U stated hardware limitations.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments and answers.  Your suggestions have convinced me that a dictionary is not the right answer to this problem and I'll be re-factoring my code to use a list now.  I upvoted all the comments and answers even though I can only accept a single answer.  Thanks again to all of you!

Comment: I say Array over List if you know the size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d[d.FirstOrDefault(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value)).Key] = "My String";
```

However, a dictionary is really meant to store true key-value pairs. A list sounds like it is better suited to your case where it seems like you only really need to store values. Even so, list elements are still accessible by index and you can include empty elements so there doesn't (from what you have stated) seem to be a reason to stick with a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

A `Dictionary` might not be the best choice for what you are trying to do. Try a simple `List<>` or an array.

A `Dictionary` is an optimized way to map one unique value to another non-unique one. If you are trying to do anything more than that, you are better implementing your own collection.

Answer (score 1):

If you know there will be an entry with an empty string value you can use:

```
var kvp = d.First(p => p.Value == string.Empty);
d[kvp.Key] = "new string goes here!";
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend it, as the comments say, you should use a list. But here's two examples:

```
  Dictionary<int, string> d = new Dictionary<int, string>();
  string valueToBeInserted = "randomstring";
  var keyValuePair = d.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Value == string.Empty);
  d[keyValuePair.Key] = valueToBeInserted;
```

Simplified:

```
 Dictionary<int, string> d = new Dictionary<int, string>();
 string valueToBeInserted = "randomstring";
 d[d.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Value == string.Empty).Key] = valueToBeInserted;
```